# Рассчитать угол поворота пушки

Tags: c++, математика

Есть координаты курсора и пушки. Как рассчитать угол поворота пушки так, чтобы она смотрела на курсор?

Comment: используйте формулу для скалярного произведения векторов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так получилось сделать:

```
float x = mouseX - Tank.getX();
float y = mouseY - Tank.getY();
float angle = atan2(y, x);

Tank.setGunAngle(angle/3.14159265359*180);
```