# Угол поворота башни танка на цель на координатной плоскости

Tags: delphi, математика, vector, координаты

Такая задачка на Delphi вычислить угол поворота пушки танка нацель на координатной плоскости.
Пушка вращается на 360 градусов, координаты центра башни(X1, Y1) и цели(X2, Y2) известны и всегда > 0, Угол текущего поворота пушки (A) относительно оси Y также известен. На какой угол нужно повернуть башню чтобы пушка смотрела на цель? Помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос содержит два не связанны: 1) Как это вычислить математически 2) Как это запрограммировать на Delphi. Укажите конкретную проблему, всё домашнее задание за вас тут делать никто не будет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Рассчитать угол поворота пушки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421063/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единичный вектор направления пушки

```
dx = Cos(a)
dy = Sin(a)
```

Вектор цели

```
tx = x2 - x1
ty = y2 - y1
```

Угол доворота пушки

```
f := Math.ArcTan2(dx*ty-dy*tx, dx*tx+dy*ty);
```

На всякий случай добавлю: угол, под которым будет смотреть пушка:

```
a_new := Math.ArcTan(ty, tx);
```

Пример

```
procedure TForm2.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
   x1, y1, tx, ty: integer;
   a: Double;
begin
  x1 := Paintbox1.Width div 2;
  y1 := PaintBox1.Height div 2;
  tx := X - x1;
  ty := Y - y1;
  a := ArcTan2(ty, tx);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.FillRect(Paintbox1.ClientRect);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  Paintbox1.Canvas.Ellipse(x1-3, y1-3, x1 + 4, y1+4);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.MoveTo(x1, y1);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.LineTo(x1+Round(30*Cos(a)), y1+Round(30*Sin(a)));
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `dx := sin(User.Angle);
     dy := cos(User.Angle);
     x1 :=  User.X;
     y1 :=  User.Y;
     x2  :=  Target.X;
     y2  :=  Target.Y;
     tx := x2 - x1;
     ty := y2 - y1;
     angle:= Atan2(dx*ty-dy*tx, dx*tx+dy*ty);
     angle:= (angle * 180/ Pi );
     setangle(Round(angle - User.Angle));`

Крутит башней по кругу и всё, что я делю не так? @MBo

Comment: Если вам нужно установить абсолютный угол, а не насколько повернуть, то я в конце дописывал (a'). Кроме того, есть сомнения, в каких единицах у вас углы - cos, sin нужен аргумент в радианах, а не в градусах.

Comment: Я делал angle := Atan2(ty, tx);  angle:= (angle * 180/ Pi );   setangle(Round(angle));
Бот поворачивается на куда угодно, но не нацель, причем закономерности я не нашел .

Comment: Посмотрите на рабочий код

Comment: Я понял в чем дело, в просто в игре полный оборот не 360 градусов, а 128 попугаев. Поэтому фигня творится. Теперь бы понять как это дело привести к 360 градусам.  Спасибо за оказанную помощь и терпение к тупости.

Comment: Все получилось:` dx := sin(User.Angle * 2.8125 * Pi/ 180);
dy := cos(User.Angle * 2.8125 * Pi/ 180); setangle(Round((angle/ 2.8125) - (user.angle)));`

Comment: Вот как, всё-таки дело в угловых единицах.. Про setangle - оно задаёт абсолютный угол или изменение относительно текущего положения?

Comment: Абсолютный угол.

Comment: Тогда считайте по второй, короткой формуле, и вычитать (user.angle) не придётся

Comment: Если ответ помог, не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer